# Back button is not working in the VideoCastControllerAcitivity of the CastCompanionLibrary

Tags: android, google-cast

I'm unable to get the Android back button to work in my personal app when my device is on the `VideoCastControllerActivity view`. The button does not work regardless if I call `finish()` in the `Activity` that calls `VideoCastManager.startCastControllerActivity()`.

Is there any configuration that needs to be performed to get the back button to work for the `CastController activity`?

BTW the back button is working for me in the CastVideo-android app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please update your CCL library, it should work now; probably you were not setting the VOLUME_INCREMENT; I have adjust to account for that.